# How to prevent a modal from being drawn more than once?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

This is a bit more abstract than the usual questions which I know goes against the spirit of things, but I'm hoping that I can still get a good response.

Here's the issue. We have a fairly complex web application that is written in PHP. The purpose is relatively unimportant, but simply put: We are using Comet / AJAX / JSON / **JavaScript** / PHP  / MySQL (NO jQuery, however, native JavaScript only) to render controls that display data in real time. Throughout this application we are rendering popup modals using **native JavaScript**. It's fairly complex logic that tests for the existence of a modal with the same name on the page and prevents creating new versions of the same, and of course once created a layer is created to prevent interacting with links beneath.

The issue is that we have at least one modal that can be called multiple times before it is rendered on the page due to the time it takes the AJAX call to collect data from the database and assemble it for presentation. If a user were to 'double click' on said link they would be presented with two modals, one on top of the other. I've been able to actually render 8-10 of these. Interacting with the topmost modal appears to be broken because the user is actually effecting collapsible headers on the bottom-most modal. Once you start closing the dialog boxes and get to the bottom you can see where you've clicked.

So, my issue is this: What is the best way to prevent this behavior?

I've considered simply adding a function to the onClick event that would remove the onClick attribute from the link after the first click with a minor timeout (say 500ms). I've also considered trying to implement bit testing logic that would count clicks and only actually first the event after the first click and reset when the modal is closed.

What I'm wondering is if someone has any thoughts or suggestions or even has tackled a similar issue and has some insight on best practices to accomplish my goal in this instance.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could always try [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Would that I could. As much as I'd love to use jQuery on this project, the project manager is wholly and completely against non-native JavaScript. Thank you for the suggestion, though. I should have included that information in the post to be clearer.

Comment: Ah, shame. It might've been worth mentioning that you're not using jQuery as many readers (myself included) often assume its' presence

Comment: @fyrephlie Could you not check in to the source code of jquery and look how .one() is constructed, then apply the same logic to your application in pure javascript?

Comment: @StenW While I suppose I could do that, I think it would be well beyond the scope of my needs in this case. I'm content with the solution that I've implemented for now without having to tear into jQuery's inner-workings. Thank you though.

Comment: @Bojangles Yes, thank you for pointing that out. As I mentioned in my first reply I know I should have mentioned it in my post. I have since edited my post to say so. I would recommend never assuming anyone is using any library / framework, however... you know what they say about you when you assume.

Comment: It's a shame that one _does_ have to mention _not_ using jQuery really, although the default assumption from readers should always be that jQuery is not in use if it's not mentioned. I fall foul of doing the opposite far too often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I found the simplest solution to be the best but I would still love to hear other feedback if'n it's out there.

In this case I found that the order of operations was the issue. I was awaiting the AJAX response to generate the body html for this modal. I changed the order to instead create the modal immediately using `<p>Loading...</p>` within the body of the modal. Then, when the AJAX was completed and I had my new body text, I just injected it into the modal's content area with a neat bit of code and Bob's your Uncle, we had jackpot.

Answer (score 4):

You can unregister the click handler once it fired:

```
var element = ...,
myClickHandler = function(event) {
    // ...
    element.removeEventListener('click', myClickHandler, false);
    // ...
}

element.addEventListener('click', myClickHandler, false);
```

Comment: I like this solution quite a bit. Thank you!